# Apache Nutch not indexing links with comma

Tags: web-crawler, relative-path, nutch

Hi I am having issue with nutch indexing.  It is not indexing links with comma.

example:
http://example.com/abc/1234/aaa,bbb

Link: http://example.com/abc/1234/aaa -> will result in 404
but link http://example.com/abc/1234/aaa,bbb -> should be indexed

anchor looks like following in html

aaa bbb

I am pretty new to Nutch so not sure what configuration skips ',' in Nutch and where to change it.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can try managing this via conf/regex-urlfilter.txt file. Look for the pattern there and try to tweak. Let me know if it works else I'll try to give a sample tomorrow.

Comment: links with comman are not ignored in regex-urlfilter.txt  the file has only following:
-^(file|ftp|mailto):
-[*!@]
-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/
+.